# user and admin login in php

Tags: php, sql

In my database, there is a row called 'role' which is specific the whether it is admin or user for login. 
Of course, admin and user have different function.
here is my login process code.

```
<?php
include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection

ini_set("session.save_path", "../../sessionData");
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$username = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'userName') ? $_POST['userName']: null;
$passWD  = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'pwd') ? $_POST['pwd']: null;

    $username = trim($username);
    $passWD = trim($passWD);

    //before we query from the database , we have to standartise 
    // create an empty array

    if (empty($username)){
    die("No username entered.");
    }

    if (empty($passWD)){
    die("No password entered.");
    }

/* Query the users database table to get the password hash for the username entered by the user in the logon form */

$sql = "SELECT password ,userID FROM t_user WHERE username = ?";


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    // prepare the sql statement

/* Bind the $username entered by the user to the prepared statement. Note the “s” part indicates the data type used – in this case a string */

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);     

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);// execute the query

/* Get the password hash from the query results for the given username and store it in the variable indicated */

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash,$userID);

/* Check if a record was returned by the query. If yes, then there was a username matching what was entered in the logon form and we can now test to see if the password entered in the logon form is the same as the stored (correct) one in the database. */

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

         $_SESSION['uName'] = $username;
         $_SESSION['uID']   = $userID;

         //PASSWORD CORRECT
       if (password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash)) {
           $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
           echo "<p>Welcome back    " .$_SESSION['uName']."</p>\n";
           echo "<p>Welcome back    " .$_SESSION['uID']."</p>\n";
        echo "<p>Password correct!</p>\n";
        echo "<p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";
    }
        else {
            echo "<p>Password incorrect.</p>\n";
        }
    }

    else {
        echo "<p>Sorry we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
    }

    //this line should determine whether it is user or admin is login 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     if($result)
        {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $user_type = $row['role']; // you get user type here whether he's admin or login

        if ($user_type == 'admin') { 

             echo " this is admin";
             //header to admin page
        }

        elseif ($user_type == 'user') {
            echo "this is user" ;
            //header to user page
        }

        else{
            echo "query failed"; 
        }
        }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code doesn't work as it should show the login role.
it seem like the role cannot be determine 
Or is there any other method to do so???

Comment: What means `The code doesn't work`?

Comment: Be more specific in your problem. So that we can help you out.

Comment: it should shows the echo statement whether it is admin or user login

Comment: if you had enabled error reporting now you should have got a warning that `role` is undifined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code doesn't work as it should show the login role. it seem like
>   the role cannot be determine

well the reason that is happening is because you have undefined index role. this line should throw a notice of undefined index : `$user_type = $row['role'];` because role is undefined on your sql statement you did not select role. this is your statement : `$sql = "SELECT password ,userID FROM t_user WHERE username = ?";` as you can see you don't select role anywhere in your code, also i don't understand what are you trying to achieve here : `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

You have already prepared a statement and executed the statement therefore you don't need to run another query to determine the user's role, this can all be done with a single query.

This is how u can achieve this :

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
ini_set("session.save_path", "../../sessionData");
include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head> 
   <body>
    <?php
$username = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'userName') ? $_POST['userName'] : null;
$passWD   = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'pwd') ? $_POST['pwd'] : null;

$username = trim($username);
$passWD   = trim($passWD);

//before we query from the database , we have to standartise 
// create an empty array

if (empty($username)) {
    die("No username entered.");
}

if (empty($passWD)) {
    die("No password entered.");
}

/* Query the users database table to get the password hash for the username entered by the user in the logon form */

$sql = "SELECT password ,userID,role FROM t_user WHERE username = ?";


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql); // prepare the sql statement

/* Bind the $username entered by the user to the prepared statement. Note the “s” part indicates the data type used – in this case a string */

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query

/* Get the password hash from the query results for the given username and store it in the variable indicated */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash, $userID, $user_type);

/* Check if a record was returned by the query. If yes, then there was a username matching what was entered in the logon form and we can now test to see if the password entered in the logon form is the same as the stored (correct) one in the database. */

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    $_SESSION['uName'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['uID']   = $userID;

    //PASSWORD CORRECT
    if (password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash)) {
        $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
        echo "<p>Welcome back    " . $_SESSION['uName'] . "</p>\n";
        echo "<p>Welcome back    " . $_SESSION['uID'] . "</p>\n";
        echo "<p>Password correct!</p>\n";
        echo "<p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";

        // check user role

        if ($user_type == 'admin') {

            echo " this is admin";
            //header to admin page
        } elseif ($user_type == 'user') {
            echo "this is user";
            //header to user page  
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Password incorrect.</p>\n";
    }
}

else {
    echo "<p>Sorry we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

> NB: is important that you enable error reporting when you are still
>   working on your localhost so that you can see these notices and small
>   errors you are doing : add at the top of your page :
>
> ```
> ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
> `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
> ```
>
> And also you must always check your server error logs located in `apache/logs/error.log`